# Using summarize_all() to find median on sparklyr data

Tags: r, dplyr, median, sparklyr

I am trying to get summary statistics for data in r that I pulled using sparklyr, including mean and median. I can get all my stats by manually typing everything out in a dplyr::summarize() step, but would like to know if there is a way to do this using a summarize_all() statement.

Manual attempt works:

```
test<-data%>%
    dplyr::summarize(count=n(),
                     mean_c1=mean(column1,na.rm=TRUE),
                     mean_c2=mean(column2,na.rm=TRUE),
                     median_c1=percentile(column1,.5),
                     median_c2=percentile(column2,.5))
```

Summarize_all() attempt works without calling percentile for the median. This gets me count,mean, min, max for my data (vars is a vector of column names)

```
test<-data%>%
    select(vars)%>%
    dplyr::summarize_all(list(count=~n(),mean=mean, min=min,max=max))
```

But I get errors when I try to add median into the mix- it no longer recognizes the
percentile command, which is a Hive function and not an r/dplyr function. ("Error in inherits(x, "fun_list") : object 'percentile' not found")

```
test<-data%>%
    select(vars)%>%
    dplyr::summarize_all(list(count=~n(),mean=mean, min=min,max=max,median=percentile),probs=.5)
```

I tried using quantile instead of percentile (which is how I would do this with a data frame), but it errors out when I call the 'test' table.

Is it possible to get median for a spark table in r using the summarize_all() command? Or will I have to do it more manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glue package solved my problem.

```
library(rlang)
library(glue)

vars<-tbl_vars(data)
eq3<-glue("percentile({vars},.5)")%>%
    setNames(paste0(vars,"_median"))%>%
    lapply(parse_quosure)
test<-data%>%
    dplyr::summarize(!!!eq3)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you married to using `summarize` to do this? because you're already using the tidyverse and the package `psych` comes with that, so you could just do

```
data %>% 
  select(vars) %>%
  psych::describe()
```

and get the same result, more or less.

Comment: I am not married to summarize_all(). I gave psych::describe() a try and am getting an error. It looks like the describe function needs a data.frame or matrix? I've got spark table and I don't think it will work with the describe function, unless I am missing something?